# Chromium with pre-installed extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I go about creating and distributing a custom Chromium web browser? It should be identical to the Google version except that some extensions are pre-installed. It should still get updates off the chrome stable channel.

Comment: Note that [Chromium](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/) != Chrome Stable. Chromium isn't associated with a channel and doesn't get updates.

Comment: I think you now can get auto updates using chromium, but you souldn't use it for anything but dev because it is not stable and could have security risks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a system administrator and want to do some custom Chrome[ium] deployments for all employees you should read this [document](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators).

There is a [guide](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions) for pre-installing extensions and web apps as well.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome doesn't have provisions to do this.

Extensions are installed per-user in their [User Data](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) directory.

If you have the liberty to do so, you could create a fresh user directory, install the desired extensions, then package up and ship that user directory as the default one.